# Work done against gravity by a man climbing up a rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, string

Question:

> A man of weight  W hangs at the end of a light extensible rope whose modulus is $nW$. The other end of the rope is fastened to a fixed point. He proceeds to climb up the rope. Prove that when he reaches the fixed point, he has done 
>   $\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$ times the work he would have done in climbing the same distance up an inextensible rope.

We can easily calculate the total length of string to be $l+\frac{l}{n}$ where $l$ is natural length of string.

But in my book it is written that the work done by the man in climbing up the rope = work done against gravity - Work done by the tension in the string = 
Wl (l+n)/n - 1/2 .w . l/ n 
I am completely helpless to understand that why  work done against grevatity is  wl (l+n)/n .  I think it should be 
Tl (l+n)/n  where T is force applied by person  to climbing up . I think $T > W$ because $T = W$, then it should be position of equilibrium.  When $T=W$, the person should not move. Please help me. This concept is totally new to me.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1):

In explaining how the work done against gravity is indeed $W*(l+l/n)$. Think of it this way; what would be the work done against gravity if you had to lift a block of weight $W$ through $h$ meters? It would have to be its increase in Gravitational Potential Energy(GPE) which is $Wh$ as any more force greater than $W$ would cause the block to **not** be stationary. Hence it’s the same for the man on the rope. His work done against gravity is his increase in GPE( Note how GPE uses a force which is very close or approximately equal to the weight that can *just* lift the object through a distance).

**Note**:You mistakenly put an extra $l$ in the energy equation giving it units of $Nm^2$ but it instead should be just be $W*(l+l/n)$ so it has units of $Nm$ as energy is = force x distance moved in direction of force